# Laravel gives an error for logout when the session timedout

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project when i click on logout and if the session is timed out it shows and error for token miss match.But i want like it goes to the login page.how to solve this.

[image]

In other pages when session timedout it goes to the login page i want same for the logout.

in my web all other pages are under the following auth middleware thats may be the reason other pages works fine.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'changepassword']], function () 
{ }
```

Comment: Isn't this a `VerifyCsrfToken` error? Could you post the full error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the logout route to the VerifyCsrfToken exceptions list:

```
protected $except = [
    'your/logout/route'
];
```

You can find the class in App/Http/Middleware. If you have any code doing stuff in the logout function that you only want logged in users to be able to, then you would have to add checks to see if the user session has timed out and act accordingly.

Comment: what is your in 'your/logout/route' ?

Comment: the route that you have bound to your logout function. The url that you send your user to to log them out.

Comment: Yes it works i replace it by 'logout' and it works thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Just make sure you don't have any code in the function connected to that route that could pose a security threat!